# Writing negative integer as 0xnn hex into peripheral

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, integer, signed

I am dealing with a hardware peripheral which exposes a writable characteristics for Measured Power. As per the specs from the hardware vendor Measured Power should be sent in the format "0xnn". I am not sure how do we convert a negative integer (-59) into 1 byte hex representation (0xnn).

By far I have tried below

```
int iPower = -59;
int16_t power = CFSwapInt16HostToBig(iPower);
NSData *powerData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&power length:sizeof(power)];
```

But this writes 0xFF into peripheral which is 255 in decimal. Any idea?

Even tried sending raw bytes by below code and this reaches as 0xC5 which is 197 in decimal.

```
NSInteger index = -59;
NSData *powerData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&index length:sizeof(index)];
```

Comment: In which variable the negative integer (-59) you are storing? are you storing in char or int? what is the maximum value that a variable can take?

Comment: Are you sure you need **two** bytes and hexadecimal representation? I'd assume that what the device expects is rather **one** byte, represented as a 2's complement signed integer. (And the hexadecimal notation is just there for the sake of human-readability.)

Comment: @H2CO3 You are right. It is just one byte. And I am not sure how to send negative integer in single byte. Any idea?

Comment: @Abhinav Just send the raw byte as-is.

Comment: @H2CO3 I tried sending raw bytes but it reached as 197 decimal on hardware. Please see my updated question. Am I missing sommething?

Comment: @Abhinav 197 + 59 = 256. It seems that your device expects an unsigned integer (i. e. whatever you send it, it will interpret the data as non-negative, so you can't send -59.)

Comment: It may well be that further study of the documentation will reveal that there is another way to specify a negative value.  But, one might observe, there's no such thing as "negative power".

Comment: You wrote: _I am still figuring it out. I am also talking to my hardware vendor._ So what is the vendor saying?

Answer (score 1):

```
I am not sure how do we convert a negative integer (-59) into 2 bytes hex representation (0xnn).
```

When you have two bytes for hex representation that means you can have a range of `0x0000 ~ 0xFFFF` numbers or `0~65535` for non-negative integers or in 2's compliment representation `-32768 ~ 23767`.

By using 2's complement representation `-59` in two byte hex will be `0xFFC5`.

Also check if you really need to use this: "CFSwapInt16HostToBig"

Comment: I had tried this. Sending 0xFFC5 reaches as 0xFF on device which is 255 in decimal. Also, I have corrected my question. It is not 2 bytes, it is only 1 byte I need to send -59 in.

Comment: Well, first you need to determine if the device is indeed a 2's complement device.  It could be 1's complement, it could be sign/magnitude.

Comment: @Abhinav Okay.. thats

Comment: @Abhinav Okay... That's not a problem.. `Hot Licks` has mentioned an important point, please do consider it!.. well, have you tried 0xC5 for one byte case?

Comment: @tod Yes. I tried with 0xC5 but it reached as 197 decimal on hardware.

Comment: @Abhinav True.. i.e., `197=0xC5 or-59(in 2's compliment)` an 8-bit binary number which is displayed as `197` means that and binary value in these 8 bits will not be displayed as negative value. Please read the manual carefully ... there is no magic/logic left involved here :)

Comment: An 8-bit(1-byte) number in signed representation in 2's compliment will have a range of `-128 ~ 127`

Comment: @Abhinav Did you get some solution for it? Could you share?

Comment: @tod I am still figuring it out. I am also talking to my hardware vendor.